# Sort a python dictionary by order of items on list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary like `{'james': 32, 'jacob': 43, 'marie': 3}`.

How do I sort the dictionary assuming I have a list like `['marie', 'jacob', 'james']`, so that the new dictionary would be sorted by the order of the items in the list?

i.e, outcome:

```
{'marie': 3, 'jacob': 43, 'james': 32}
```

Comment: you cannot sort a dictionary

Comment: do you just want to access in the order of the list elements?.

Comment: You could create a new one though. But that's time consuming. I'd ask myself: does it make any difference? What is the purpose? If it's important to have the data sorted you could just use a `list` or `numpy.Array` even, presumably. Why would you need to sort it?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot sort a dictionary, but you can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) here:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> lst = ['marie', 'jacob', 'james']
>>> d = {'james': 32, 'jacob': 43, 'marie': 3}
>>> OrderedDict(zip(lst, itemgetter(*lst)(d)))
OrderedDict([('marie', 3), ('jacob', 43), ('james', 32)])
```

Answer (score 1):

As "undefined is not a function" wrote, dictionaries are not sorted (despite what their name suggests), but `collections.OrderedDict` dictionaries are.

I would write the solution in an arguably clearer way (and only with basic Python), though:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> names = ['marie', 'jacob', 'james']
>>> my_dict = {'james': 32, 'jacob': 43, 'marie': 3}
>>> OrderedDict((name, my_dict[name]) for name in names)
OrderedDict([('marie', 3), ('jacob', 43), ('james', 32)])
```

This solution also takes less memory than the `zip()` approach of "undefined is not a function", since no intermediate list is constructed (in Python 2)—it may matter, in the general case—, though this could be remedied to by replacing `zip()` with `itertools.izip()`, but that would make the `itemgetter()` solution even heavier (with two additional imports) when Python can, like in this solution, perfectly handle the question directly and in a clear way.

As Aleksander Lidtke mentioned, maybe you don't need to create a new, sorted dictionary in the first place. Maybe looping on the names would be enough:

```
for name in names:
    … my_dict[name] …
```